How to Remap or Extract sensor_msgs/Image[] Topics for Web Video Server? (ROS 1)
I’m working on a web UI using ROS 1 and the web_video_server to display camera streams. However, I’ve encountered an issue with a custom message type we’re using in our project and need some help.
Problem:
Our code publishes a custom message on the topic /custom_data/imgs. This message type is an array of images (sensor_msgs/Image[]). Unfortunately, web_video_server does not seem to recognize the array elements as valid topics.
For example, trying:
http://localhost:8080/stream?topic=/custom_data/imgs[0]
results in the server not recognizing it as a valid topic.
I understand that I need to somehow split or remap the individual images from /custom_data/imgs into separate topics like /custom_data/img0, /custom_data/img1, etc. However, I’m not allowed to modify the ROS code that publishes the original topic. I need a way to handle this using terminal commands or launch files only.
What I’ve Tried:
I attempted using rosbag play with --topics and remapping syntax, but since /custom_data/imgs is an array, I couldn’t access individual elements like /custom_data/imgs[0].
The raw message structure is out of my control, so I’m looking for solutions that don’t require code changes.
What I Need Help With:
Is there a way to extract individual images from the array into separate topics using a terminal command or a launch file?
How can I remap or create new topics (e.g., /custom_data/img0, /custom_data/img1) from the array elements?
Is there any workaround or utility that can help with this, so that web_video_server can display the streams properly?

You may be able to use https://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools to spawn a ROS node from the CLI that will subscribe to the array and republish just the first element. But nowadays I would strongly recommend webrtc for video streaming from robots to the web. Here is why: https://transitiverobotics.com/blog/streaming-video-from-robots/

Thank you! topic_tools worked! The web ui will only be running on a secure local network, but if we decide to stream to the web then I will try https://wiki.ros.org/webrtc_ros

Great! Could you post what you did using topic_tools as an answer for future visitors of this question?

Yes! From the https://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform documentation I used "transform":  transform <input> <output_topic> <output_type> [<expression>] [--import <module> [<module> ...]].  In the terminal I ran:  rosrun topic_tools transform /custom_data /custom_data_img0 sensor_msgs/Image 'm.imgs[0]' --import sensor_msgs custom_msgs

Thanks, but I really meant as an answer to your own questions, so everyone can see that this is solved and what the solution was.

(Copied here from comments for future reference.)
Using https://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform:
rosrun topic_tools transform /custom_data /custom_data_img0 \
  sensor_msgs/Image 'm.imgs[0]' --import sensor_msgs custom_msgs

